# Pyarmor in python 3.8 ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyarmor

I have problem, i'm in ubuntu use python 3.8 i have install pyarmor in my computer

`pip install pyarmor`

like this but when i try to start him from my terminal

`pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile " main.py`

Appear command not found in my terminal. When i write in terminal for check the version of pyarmore write the same command cant found.  i cant do something and i have dont find solutions in google

how can i resolve this?

Comment: are you sure `pip` works with `Python 3.8`? Maybe you should use `pip3` or `pip3.8` to install it because `pip` may install for `Python 2`. You can check version with `pip -V`

Comment: maybe it needs to install as root - `sudo pip ...` - to create link for program `pyarmor`. If I install with `sudo` then I can run it - and `which pyarmor` shows location `/usr/local/bin/pyarmor`. Tested on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) and Python 3.8

Comment: version : pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
And i have try with root and without

Comment: use some tool for searching files on disk and try to find `pyarmor`. And then run using  `/full/path/to/pyarmor`